# A loop for adding multiple columns into a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

The purpose of the following loop is to create 10 columns and name them as'col_20','col_21'...
.This loop could be created but a syntax error occurred when I tried to run it.

This is what got after I called MYLOOP() in Mysql

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1"

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE MYLOOP()
BEGIN  
          DECLARE i int;
          DECLARE str varchar(255);
          SET i = 20;
          WHILE i < 30 DO
                   SET str = CONCAT('col_',i);
                   SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE TEST ADD '+ str + ' INT;';
                   SET i = i + 1;
                   PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
                   EXECUTE stmt;
                   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
          END WHILE;
     END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL MYLOOP();
```

Comment: is this just to play around? because if your design calls for 20+ identically named columns, then you should normalize the design and split those repetitive fields into their own child table.

Comment: Agree with @MarcB.  However, the error you are receiving is because the `+` operator is for arithmetic addition, not string concatenation.  To concatenate strings, use MySQL's [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! Well..I just want to create those identical named columns for my research dataset.I replaced '+'operator by CONCAT() and it workd =)

Comment: adding columns like this is a baaaad idea. normalize your design