# Adding multiple columns to MySQL table using PHP loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, alter

**My objective**

To add a number of columns to a MySQL table. I have two concerns:

1) How to do this

2) Is this a bad idea, and if so why?

**My reason for wanting to do this:**

I have a form with a systematically named set of fields (e.g. field_1 field_2 etc). I want to post that data to a page and have it store it the mysql table, and I would like the fields to enter columns of a corresponding name (i.e. columns are named field_1 field_2 etc)

Rather than manually creating a column for each field name manually, it seemed obvious to loop the task.

However, research [here](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/272434-while-loop-and-alter-mysql/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844027/a-loop-for-adding-multiple-columns-into-a-table-in-mysql) seems tells me this approach illicits horror from people, and I found no actual solutions.

**My attempt:**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","user","password","db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}    

$i = 1;
while ($i <= 14)
{
    $column = 'field_'.$i;
    $sql= '"ALTER TABLE supply ADD '.$column.' VARCHAR(45)"';
    $mysqli->query($sql);
    printf("Affected rows (ALTER): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);
$i++;
}
```

This seems to run without error, however the affected rows message gives me (per loop, so 14 of these):

> Affected rows (ALTER): -1

and the columns are not being added.

Can anyone advise me of my error, or a better way to debug what is going wrong? Additionally if this is an unwise thing to be doing could could you explain why and what I should consider doing instead? Thank you.

Comment: why you used both single and double quotes? `'"ALTER TABLE supply ADD '.$column.' VARCHAR(45)"'`?

Comment: Becuase the double quotes are (I think) a part of the query syntax, and the single quotes are bounding the definition of the variable. I was attempting to emulate this syntax as seen on php.net: `$mysqli->query("ALTER TABLE Language ADD Status int default 0");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because `affected_rows` are set when you use only statements:

- **INSERT**
- **UPDATE**
- **REPLACE**
- **DELETE**

which work with rows, with data inside your table.

When you use `ALTER` your result should be `true` or `false`, because you do not work with data, you just edit the structure of your table.

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) ;
if ($result){
  echo "Table is updated. New column {$column} added" ;
}
```

Also, the correct SQL here would be:

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE supply ADD {$column} VARCHAR(45) ; " ;
```

Comment: Ah ha, ok great thank you, I've made that adjustment and am getting no return now. My full syntax now looks like:
http://ideone.com/1sHOzt
Is this what you'd expect?

Comment: Well, I personally always use semicolons inside sql. What error do you get?

Comment: Sorry - just deleted my comment as realised I had just typod something - your solution works perfectly, all columns now created. Thank you very much!

Comment: No prob, glad you figured that out!